# Why deepcopy of list of integers returns the same integers in memory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-copy

I understand the differences between shallow copy and deep copy as I have learnt in class. However the following doesn't make sense

```
import copy

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 

b = copy.deepcopy(a)

print(a is b)
print(a[0] is b[0])
----------------------------
~Output~
>False
>True
----------------------------
```

Shouldn't `print(a[0] is b[0])` evaluate to False as the objects and their constituent elements are being recreated at a different memory location in a deep copy? I was just testing this out as we had discussed this in class yet it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 19):

It was suggested in another answer that this may be due to the fact Python has interned objects for small integers. While this statement is correct, it is not what causes that behaviour.

Let's have a look at what happens when we use bigger integers.

```
> from copy import deepcopy
> x = 1000
> x is deepcopy(x)
True
```

If we dig down in the `copy` module we find out that calling `deepcopy` with an atomic value defers the call to the function [`_deepcopy_atomic`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/copy.py#L182).

```
def _deepcopy_atomic(x, memo):
    return x
```

So what is actually happening is that `deepcopy` will not copy an atomic value, but only return it.

By example this is the case for `int`, `float`, `str`, `function` and more.

Comment: Good answer; +1. I think it's worth noting that `deepcopy` does copy non-atomic immutable values like tuples if they have mutable components, like `([1, 2], [3, 4])`.

Comment: @kaya3 thanks for catching this! You are right, I should have said 'atomic', not immutable.

Answer (score 9):

The reason of this behavior is that Python optimize small integers so they are not actually in different memory location. Check out the `id` of `1`, they are always the same:

```
>>> x = 1
>>> y = 1
>>> id(x)
1353557072
>>> id(y)
1353557072

>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> id(a[0])
1353557072

>>> import copy
>>> b = copy.deepcopy(a)
>>> id(b[0])
1353557072
```

---

Reference from [Integer Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html):

> The current implementation keeps an array of integer objects for all integers between `-5` and `256`, when you create an int in that range you actually just get back a reference to the existing object. So it should be possible to change the value of `1`. I suspect the behaviour of Python in this case is undefined. :-)

Comment: Isnt what youre describing the principal of "shallow copies" i.e copy.copy(a), when using copy.deepcopy(a), shouldnt the elements all be in different memory locations, i.e that id(a[0]) != id(b[0])

Comment: @GeraldLee: This is a special case, in that the 'small' integers (`< 257`) will be fixed to memory location to speed up common operations. Try the following: `a, b = (list(range(258)), list(range(258)));[id(a[i]) == id(b[i]) for i in range(258)]` in a python REPL

Comment: Small ints are examples of Python singletons. Others are `None`, `True`, and `False`

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the reason; the same behaviour can be observed for larger numbers or strings, which are not cached.

Answer (score 3):

Olivier Melançon's answer is the correct one if we take this as a mechanical question of how the `deepcopy` function call ends up returning references to the same `int` objects rather than copies of them. I'll take a step back and answer the question of why that is the sensible thing for `deepcopy` to do.

The reason we need to make copies of data structures - either deep or shallow copies - is so we can modify their contents without affecting the state of the original; or so we can modify the *original* while still keeping a copy of the old state. A deep copy is needed for that purpose when a data structure has nested parts which are themselves mutable. Consider this example, which multiplies every number in a 2D grid, like `[[1, 2], [3, 4]]`:

```py
import copy

def multiply_grid(grid, k):
    new_grid = copy.deepcopy(grid)
    
    for row in new_grid:
        for i in range(len(row)):
            row[i] *= k
    
    return new_grid
```

Objects such as lists are mutable, so the operation `row[i] *= k` changes their state. Making a copy of the list is a way to defend against mutation; a deep copy is needed here to make copies of both the outer list and the inner lists (i.e. the rows), which are also mutable.

But objects such as integers and strings are immutable, so their state cannot be modified. If an `int` object is 13 then it will stay 13, even if you multiply it by `k`; the multiplication results in a different `int` object. There is no mutation to defend against, and hence no need to make a copy.

Interestingly, `deepcopy` doesn't need to make copies of tuples if their components are all immutable*, but it does when they have mutable components:

```py
>>> import copy
>>> x = ([1, 2], [3, 4])
>>> x is copy.deepcopy(x)
False
>>> y = (1, 2)
>>> y is copy.deepcopy(y)
True
```

The logic is the same: if an object is immutable but has nested components which are mutable, then a copy is needed to avoid mutation to the components of the original. But if the whole structure is completely immutable, there is no mutation to defend against and hence no need for a copy.

<sub>* As Kelly Bundy points out in the comments, `deepcopy` sometimes does make copies of deeply-immutable objects, for example it does generally make copies of `frozenset` instances. The principle is that it doesn't *need* to make copies of those objects; it is an implementation detail whether or not it does in some specific cases.</sub>

Comment: "doesn't make copies of tuples if their components are all immutable" - `(1, frozenset({2}))` for example [does get copied](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/PzO3IL@oRCE5v6CSq1LBVkHDUEchrSi/KjWvOLVEo9qoVlOTq6AoM69Eo1IhsxisTi8lNbUAxNCo1NT8/x8A).

Comment: @KellyBundy Thank you, fixed. Looks like the same applies for all non-empty `frozenset`s regardless of if they're in tuples, and presumably the only reason empty `frozenset` instances don't get copied is because `frozenset.__new__` handles that as a special case.

Comment: Hmm, even the empty frozenset got copied for me. Apparently since Python 3.10. Anyway, for tuples there's [special code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ed55426acd58f030ccc0cf1297e66078f538797c/Lib/copy.py#L210-L225) in the `copy` module, for `frozenset` there isn't. I wonder why. Maybe just not deemed important. I think it could be done similarly.