# How to arrange an existing Python list of integers consecutively in memory?

Tags: python, integer, copy, deep-copy

The following blog post shows that a list of integers is processed quicker if the list is not randomly shuffled. Due to cache locality, the unshuffled list is faster to process since its adjacent elements are located adjacently in memory.

https://rickystewart.wordpress.com/2013/09/03/why-sorting-an-array-makes-a-python-loop-faster/

I tried the following approach so that the shuffled list would be re-ordered with adjacent elements consecutive in memory.

```
import copy
a = [i for i in range(1000000)]
shuffle(a)
# Approach 1
a = copy.deepcopy(a)
```

However, that did not improve performance, suggesting that the items aren't reordered consecutively in memory.

I also tried the following modifications after shuffling, which also did not improve performance.

```
# Approach 2
a = [x for x in a]

# Approach 3
a = [copy.deepcopy(x) for x in a]
```

The following approach improves performance, suggesting that the elements are re-ordered in memory.

```
# Approach 4
a = [x+0 for x in a]
```

My question is why do approaches 1 through 3 not re-order the elements in memory, whereas approach 4 does?

Is there a suggested way to do this, different from approach 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It boils down to whether you are creating new objects or not. It turns out approaches 1 to 3 do not create new objects, here is why.

### Approach 1 & 3: ❌

While they look different, those two approaches are the same. When calling `copy.deepcopy` on an integer [(or any immutable builtin type)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48124497/5079316), the `copy` module uses the following method.

```
def _deepcopy_atomic(x, memo):
    return x
```

So whenever you deepcopy an integer, the *same* object is returned. Likewise, deepcopying an list of integers actually returns a shallow copy.

```
from copy import deepcopy

l = [1000]
print(l[0] is deepcopy(l)[0]) # True
```

### Approach 2: ❌

By doing `[x for x in a]`, you trivially make a new list with exactly the same objects. Here is a sanity check.

```
l1 = [1000]
l2 = [x for x in l1]

print(l1[0] is l2[0]) # True
```

### Approach 4: ✅

Now this approach actually creates a new object for integers bigger than 256.

```
x = 1000
print(x is x + 0) # False
```

## Final word

While the last approach is the only one that actually creates a new object, I could not find anything in the doc stating that this is a property of the language. So keep in mind that this might be implementation specific and that it is not unlikely to encounter an interpret which optimizes `x + 0` to always return the same object.

Comment: Do you know of any way that guarantees a new object will be created?

Comment: @DanielS. I could not find a way that was documented. Moreover, I could not find a way that is faster, or more elegant, than doing x+0