# Force copy of a small int in Python

Tags: python, int, copy

As a toy problem, I tried to come up with objects `a, b` such that

```
type(a) == type(b) == int # True
a + 1 == b + 1 == 1       # True
a is b                    # False
```

It seems that `deepcopy`falls back on `_deepcopy_atomic`, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31621997/why-deepcopy-of-list-of-integers-returns-the-same-integers-in-memory).

Is it possible to create a copy of a small int in Python?

Comment: I can't think of a way from inside Python (but I won't answer, as I can't prove a negative :P ). You could create a native module that would construct a new integer object with a given value, but that may or may not break things. Out of curiosity, why do you want a copy of an immutable object?

Comment: Amadan I don’t have a precise notion of copy in mind, I guess I would settle for messing with Python’s ‘is’ behavior :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, and without low level hacks or cheats:

```
>>> a = 0
>>> b = 9**99 % 9**99
>>> type(a) == type(b) == int
True
>>> a + 1 == b + 1 == 1
True
>>> a is b
False
```

I'm doing this locally with Python 3.8.1, but you can also reproduce it [at repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/YellowgreenGrippingSyndrome) and at [www.python.org/shell/](https://www.python.org/shell/).

For small positives:

```
>>> a = 7
>>> b = (9**99 + a) % 9**99
>>> b, type(b), a == b, a is b
(7, <class 'int'>, True, False)
```

For small negatives:

```
>>> a = -2
>>> b = (9**99 + a) % -9**99
>>> b, type(b), a == b, a is b
(-2, <class 'int'>, True, False)
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question depends on what you consider to be a *small int*. As per [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html#c.PyLong_FromLong):

> The current implementation keeps an array of integer objects for all integers between -5 and 256, when you create an int in that range you actually just get back a reference to the existing object.

In the case of integers, line `a is b` is equivalent to `id(a) == id(b)`. For the range `[-5, 256]` ids for all of the numbers are predefined, which means that `a` and `b` act as aliases for the existing object.

The only way in which `a, b` would satisfy your condition `a + 1 == b + 1 == 1` is when `a = b = 0`. Since `0` is in the aforementioned range, it is not possible to make `a is b` return `False`.

Comment: Thanks, the link was very helpful, especially this: "So it should be possible to change the value of 1". We can edit a memory location of an int to get the behavior I was after.

Answer (score 2):

This likely isn't the intent of the question, but the 3 assertions in the question can be satisfied if `int` is allowed to be overridden, such that the following code will pass:

```
int = type('', (int,), dict(vars(int)))
a = int(0)
b = int(0)
assert type(a) == type(b) == int
assert a + 1 == b + 1 == 1
assert a is not b
```

Comment: ha, fair enough. In the same spirit one could define `type = lambda x: int` and use custom classes for `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the following to work for CPython:

```
import ctypes

x = 2
y = 3

ctypes.c_int.from_address(id(y) + 24).value = x

print(x == y) # True
print(x is y) # False
```

I couldn't get away with `x = 0` or `x = 1` without crashing the interpreter.